# X-editable Select2 Tags with Spring MVC

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, jquery-select2, x-editable

I'm using the X-editable plugin to update a form with multiple fields and data types. Each element of the form has a `name` value that maps a Java attribute inside a DTO. When the form is submitted, using Ajax, all the values match the corresponding fields of the Java object *except* for the TAGS array that in theory should match a list of strings but somehow I get a `NumberFormatException`.

**Stack trace**

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:991)
```

**Select2 Tag mode**

```
$('.issue-tags').editable({
                pk: 22,
                name: 'tags',                
                placement: 'top',      
                mode: 'popup',  
                select2: {                                  
                    tags: ${tags},
                    tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
                },                 
                ajaxOptions: {
                    type: 'put'
                }
          });
```

The "tags" property loads values from a Database.

**Submit button**

```
 $('#btn-submit').click(function() {                  

      $('.editable').editable('submit', {                      

           url: './updateForm.html', 
           ajaxOptions: {
               dataType: 'json'
           },                             
           success: function(data, config) {                                
               ...                          
           },
           error: function(errors) {
              ...
           }
       });                        

});
```

**Java DTO**

```
public class MyObjectDTO implements Serializable {

    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
}
```

**Spring MVC Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/updateForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String doUpdateForm(@ModelAttribute("object") MyObjectDTO object, 
    HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException{
    ...
    }
```

Without the tags field, the form submits the data correctly to the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the changes I made to make the Select2 (tag mode) component working with Spring MVC:

**Select2 Tag Mode (JavaScript)**

```
$('#issue-tags').editable({
                pk: 22,
                name: 'tagsMap',                 
                placement: 'top',      
                mode: 'popup',                   
                emptytext: 'No hay etiquetas definidas',
                inputclass: 'input-large',
                select2: {              
                    tags: ${allTags},
                    tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
                    id: function (item) {
                        return item.text;
                    }
                },                  
                ajaxOptions: {
                    type: 'put'
                }   
          });
```

Where `tagsMap` is an object of my DTO class that holds the tags upon submit:

**Select 2 Tag Mode (HTML input)**

```
<a id="issue-tags" href="#" data-type="select2">${tagsByObject}</a>
```

Where `tagsByObject` contains a string of tags separated by commas, used by Select2 to display the **specific tags of my object**.

**Java DTO**

```
public class MyObjectDTO implements Serializable {

    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Map<String, Object> tagsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ...
}
```

Where `allTags` is a **JSON object parsed as a String**, which populates the dropdown-menu of the Select2 component, displaying **all current tags persisted in my database**.

**Spring MVC Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPage(Model model,  HttpServletRequest request){
    ...
            List<String> myTags = myObjectDTO.getTags();
            String tagsByComma = StringUtils.EMPTY;
            String allTags = StringUtils.EMPTY;

            if(!myTags.isEmpty()){
                for(int i = 0; i < myTags.size(); i++){
                    tagsByComma += myTags.get(i) + ", ";
                }               
                tagsByComma = tagsByComma.substring(0, tagsByComma.length() -2);
            }

            List<String> dbTags = myService.getTags();
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            for(String s : dbTags){
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("id", dbTags.indexOf(s));
                obj.put("text", s);
                array.put(obj);
            }

            allTags = array.toString();


            model.addAttribute("tagsByObject", tagsByComma);
            model.addAttribute("allTags", allTags.length() == 0 ? "[{}]" : allTags);
    ...
}
```

**Submit** function remains untouched.